# How to collapse a D3JS tree based on a user selected depth?

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I have a D3JS tree that needs to be collapsed based on a level selected by the user. There is a drop down with levels(Using Select2), from which the user can perform a selection.

I am able to do this, but, the problem is there is a delay of few seconds when the collapse function is called(Expand works fine). Here is what I am doing :

```
$("#drop_down_levels").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {                
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            if (d.depth >=e.object.id){
                 d._children = d.children;
                 d.children = null;
            }else{
                expand(d);
            }
            update(root);
            centerNode(root);
        });
    })
```

Is there a way this could be optimized? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the `update` and `centerNode` could be called outside of the loop

Comment: @HuguesStefanski : That worked perfectly !! Thank you so very much.